# Call an API 2 secs after user has key some values

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am wondering if there is a way to call an API in few secs after user has entered the values.

This logic is implemented in `Saga middleware` where `takeLatest` keyword is being used to take the latest value and make an api call.

```
import { takeLatest} from 'redux-saga/effects';

function* watchTheRequest() {
    const watcher = yield takeLatest('SOME_TYPE', callMySaga);
    yield take(LOCATION_CHANGE);
    yield cancel(watcher);
}
```

I am trying to implement the same in React UseEffect hook.

**Requirement is:** Once users stops typing, make an API call.

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
useEffect(() => {
    //wait for user to stop updating the search.
    // call API.
}, [search])
```

Not sure if I need to use either of the following to achieve this task

```
var intervalID = setInterval(alert, 1000); 
setTimeout(alert, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's called 'debounce' probably. Minimalistic implementation with useEffect:

```
const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

const toBeCalled = () => {
 // call your API here
}

useEffect(() => {
   const timer = setTimeout(toBeCalled, 1000);
   return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [search]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's called `Debounce` technique, [you can check it out here](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/debounce-your-search-react-input-optimization-fd270a8042b)

You can try with this implementation

```
const timeoutId = useRef();
const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

const onSearchChange = (newSearchTerm) => {
  // Wait for 300ms after users stop typing
  // then dispatch to get the suggestions
  clearTimeout(timeoutId.current);

  timeoutId.current = setTimeout(() => {
    if (newSearchTerm.length >= 2) {
      dispatch(getSuggestions(newSearchTerm));
    }
  }, 300);
};
```

Comment: What is this getSuggestions and dispatch method here. I am not using any redux hook. Just a simple API call.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using React 18 you can use **useDeferredValue**

```
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("")
  const deferredSearch = useDeferredValue(search)
  useEffect(() => {
     //wait for user to stop updating the search.
     // call API.
  }, [deferredSearch])
  ......
```

}

Check this [blog](https://blog.webdevsimplified.com/2022-05/use-deferred-value/) to get more information